# sql using LIKE clause : php

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm trying to generate a list of events that a user is attending. All I'm trying to do is search through columns and comparing the userid to the names stored in each column using LIKE.

Right now I have two different events stored in my database for testing, each with a unique eventID. The userid i'm signed in with is attending both of these events, however it's only displaying the eventID1 twice instead of eventID1 and eventID2.

The usernames are stored in a column called acceptedInvites separated by "~". So right now it shows "1~2" for the userid's attending. Can I just use %like% to pull these events?

```
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];  
echo "<h2>My Events</h2>";
    $myEvents = mysql_query("select eventID from events where acceptedInvites LIKE '%$userid%' ");
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($myEvents);
        foreach($fetch as $eventsAttending){
            echo $eventsAttending['eventID'];
            }
```

My output is just 11 when it should be 12

Comment: You should *really* normalize that database schema into a common one-to-many or possibly many-to-many relationship across tables. That would make this problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `foreach()`, use `while()` like this:

```
$myEvents = mysql_query("SELECT `eventID` FROM `events` WHERE `acceptedInvites` LIKE '".$userid."'");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($myEvents))
{
    echo $fetch['eventID'];
}
```

It will create a loop like `foreach()` but simpler...

**P.S.** When you make a MySQL Query, use backticks [ ` ] to ensure that the string is not confused with MySQL functions (LIKE,SELECT, etc.).

Comment: Ooh, backtits. Did you mean backticks? :P

Comment: @Joe Yeah! Sorry! I'm in Montreal, the english isn't my force!

Comment: It's fine, you'll have a hard job finding someone who doesn't like backtits :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your table setup, into a many-to-many setup (many users can attend one event, and one user can attend many events):

```
users
- id (pk, ai)
- name
- embarrassing_personal_habits

events
- id (pk, ai)
- location
- start_time

users_to_events
- user_id  ]-|
             |- Joint pk
- event id ]-|
```

Now you just use joins:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM users u
  JOIN users_to_events u2e
    ON u.id = u2e.id
  JOIN events e
    ON u2e.event_id = e.id
 WHERE u.id = 11
```

Comment: I know a bit about database normalization, I'm just not sure what commands to use to set the constraints to modify existing tables. Can you please suggest a site to read up on this? Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by your description, but I think the issue is that `mysql_fetch_array` just returns one row at a time and your code is currently set up in a way that seems to assume `$fetch` is filled with an array of all the results. You need to continuously be calling `mysql_fetch_array` for that to happen.

Instead of

```
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($myEvents);
foreach($fetch as $eventsAttending){
            echo $eventsAttending['eventID'];
            }
```

You could have

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myEvents)) {
   echo $row['eventID'];
}
```

This would cycle through the various rows of events in the table.